# Getting this error when trying to create a DB with rake db:create on google could SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I get this error when I run `rake db:create`

```
root@guidir-smaill-group-1-po7p:/home/acc/site/site# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
#<Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"pass", "host"=>"173.144.230.182", "database"=>"dbname"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

The error seems fairly common and I've read [a bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432384/error-when-trying-to-create-database-with-rails-rake-dbcreate) of posts [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952265/rake-dbcreate-generated-if-you-set-the-charset-manually-make-sure-you-have-a) on how that fixed it. But they all include removing and re installing MySQL with a command like these

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local \ --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config

sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Problem is that im using an SQL instance on google cloud and I dont want to uninstall the mysql setup they have there. How can I get the same result without re installing mysql so I can run `rake db:create` successfully?

Comment: Have you whitelisted the IP of the machine you are connecting from? Are you able to connect to the instance from the same machine using the 'mysql' client?

Comment: Yes it is whitelisted and I can connect to the mysql from the machine I'm on.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would suggest trying to reinstall the mysql gem per the instructions you have found in other posts. It should have no effect on your Cloud SQL instance, it will only reinstall the mysql client on your client machine.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this following Vadim's suggestion?

Comment: @Adam no, I cant remember how I solved this either otherwise I would add it as an answer.